# What action to take if I can't comment?

Tags: discussion

I don't have enough reputation to comment on an answer which I believe has a few flaws, so I'm wondering what action I should take instead.

According to [this page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), I should comment when I want to:

- Leave constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post

And I shouldn't comment when I am:

- Suggesting corrections that don't *fundamentally* change the meaning of the post; instead, make or suggest an edit;

I don't feel comfortable enough proposing an edit, and I do feel that the suggestions would change the answer *fundamentally* - yet wouldn't warrant it's own answer.

To give a bit of context, the answer I wanted to comment on is https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/388117/209558. I'm under the impression that the user **can** authenticate as root, however if they authenticate as a user they might need to be part of the group "lp". The only thing I have backing me up is the [Arch Linux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CUPS#Connection_Interfaces), so I don't feel quite comfortable outright suggesting an edit.

Comment: Glad you reached your 50 rep so quickly.  Took me couple weeks to reach that point.

Comment: Thanks! It took a bit of hanging around the new questions page, but I think it was worth it

Comment: I think asking on here helped too.  People read your question (it's on the Featured list), and then look up your posts, and upvote them if they think they're good-quality.  :)

Comment: Yeah for sure! I've had a few posts upvoted that are quite old. I don't care too much about the rep, but its a bit of a hassle if I can't contribute effectively

Comment: Sorry, but https://xkcd.com/386/  ;-)

Comment: That's exactly what happened

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm afraid the only answer is "spend some time on the site, get 50 reputation points and then comment". The rep limit for commenting is really low, it only takes 5 upvotes on answers or ten on questions. That's not hard to reach if you want to take part in the site. Answer or ask a few     questions and you'll get there in no time.

Once you do, you can comment freely.

Comment: +1, and favorite the question to come back for that comment, if it's still needed.

Comment: See also: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/528/117549

Answer (score -1):

An alternative to terdon's suggestion is writing your own answer. **NOTE: Writing your own answer is NOT putting a comment as an answer.** If one answer is inaccurate or has notable flaws, consider answering the question yourself.

Comment: just pointing out that the OP here had declared "...yet wouldn't warrant it's own answer"